# Math Operations w/ T extends number

Tags: typescript, math

I need to apply an affine transformation to a vector of size `T`, ex:

```js
const applyAffineTransform<T extends number> = (v: Vector<T>, m: Matrix<T + 1, T + 1>) => 
    new Vector<T + 1>([...v.values, 1]).applyMatrix(m)

applyAffineTransform(new Vector<3>([1, 2, 3]), Matrix.identity<4>(4)) // Good
applyAffineTransform(new Vector<2>([1, 2]), Matrix.identity<4>(4)) // Not good
applyAffineTransform(new Vector<4>([1, 2, 3, 4]), Matrix.identity<4>(4)) // Not good
```

The matrix needs to be one size larger than the vector, however, there is no default way to add/subtract numbers when they are types (or any type arithmetic in general)

I had been using code from [Here](https://itnext.io/implementing-arithmetic-within-typescripts-type-system-a1ef140a6f6f), however that fails in this case:

```js
export type Length<T extends any[]> = T extends { length: infer L } ? L : never;

export type BuildTuple<L extends number, T extends any[] = []> =
    T extends { length: L }
        ? T
        : BuildTuple<L, [...T, any]>;

export type Add<A extends number, B extends number> =
    Length<[...BuildTuple<A>, ...BuildTuple<B>]>;

// This fails (Type 'Add<T, 1>' does not satisfy the constraint 'number'):
type three<T extends number> = Add<Add<T, 1>, 1>
                                   ~~~~~~~~~
```

Is there a better/newer way to do this that doesn't fail?

Comment: Why does the vector size need to be a Type `T`?

Comment: That’s how big it is (we shouldn’t use vectors with only x and y for things that need x y and z)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/we4EdW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that `Length<T>` will always be a `number`; you can wrap the implementation of `Length` with `Extract<..., number>` and that should start working.  There are all kinds of hacky ways to try to do type-level arithmetic with nonnegative whole numbers, and I don't know if any of them are "better".  If you provide a self-contained [mre] then I can possibly provide more specific guidance.